# Get week day name from jquery ui calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I want to get the name of the Day when choosing date from jquery ui calender.

for example, when choosing 14-3-2012 it should returns Wednesday.

```
$("input[name=date]").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeYear:true,
    changeMonth:true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
         var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');

         //what should I write here to get the day name?

    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an array with the list of days in it ...

```
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wednesday";
weekday[4]="Thursday";
weekday[5]="Friday";
weekday[6]="Saturday";
```

Then in your onselect function get the day number and use the above array to return the day of the week

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
  var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
  var dayOfWeek = weekday[date.getUTCDay()];
  // dayOfWeek is then a string containing the day of the week

}
```

Comment: date.getUTCDay() starts with 0 as monday

Comment: @LahiruRuhunage nope .. 0 = Sunday - [read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDay) - *where 0 represents Sunday*

Comment: oh ok. but if i use like that, i always get a day ahead. so i changed monday as 0 and it wrks. y is that? may be time zone different?

Comment: @LahiruRuhunage yes probably will be timezone - getUTCDay obviously returns the UTC version ....

Answer (score 2):

There are various formats from which you can display the dates.

Check [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html) for all the date formats compatible with the calendar.

In your case `dateFormat: 'DD'` displays the WeekDays.

```
$("input[name=date]").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'DD',
    changeYear:true,
    changeMonth:true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
         alert(dateText); // alerts the day name
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Change the Format of date if you don't have problem with format.
and than apply some log to get weekday.

check this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/cnvwu/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
  var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
  var dayOfWeek = date.getUTCDay();

}
```

Comment: It returns number it seems the order of days in the week, I want to change the start day to Saturday.. The firstDay:1 means Monday, what should I specify for Saturday.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this task now and in order to get the correct day name for users who are in GMT+... timezones, we need to use the `getDay()` function, not the `getUTCDay()` function.

```
onSelect: function() {
  var weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];  
  var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
  var dayOfWeek = weekdays[date.getDay()];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code....

```
function(event, ui) {
    var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var dayOfWeek = date.getUTCDay();
};
```