# how to find day of dropped event date in fullcalnedar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar v2.0.0 in my project.I have to alert that "You can not move this event to sunday." while any event drag and droped on sunday date.

```
eventDrop : function(event,revertFunc)
{
   var day = event.start.day // my assumption 
   if(day == "Sunday")
   {
       alert("You can not move this event to sunday.");
       revertFunc();
   }
   else
   {
      //Here is my ajax to update DB
   }

}
```

I tried in google but i could not find out.

Tell me how to achieve this?

Code would be appreciable !

Comment: Did you read the doc of full calender..

Comment: This link may help you to get the things..



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700504/get-week-day-name-from-jquery-ui-calendar/9700612#9700612

Comment: @user3588674 that link not helped me

Comment: var day is it contain any value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the `moment.js` docs first. And you can format the date by using the following code: `event.start.format("dddd");`

Implementation:

```
eventDrop : function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view)
{
   var day = event.start.format("dddd"); // this will give you day 
   if(day == "Sunday")
   {
      alert("You can not move this event to sunday.");
      revertFunc();
   } else {
      //Here is my ajax to update DB
   }
}
```

Note: you are mis-placing the `revertFunc` function try the above given format.

Comment: Good answer franky and doubt on why should place that all parameter in eventDrop ? i want only event and revertFunc

Comment: does it work ? if not include blank, Parameters sequence is a must

Comment: No franky if i add all parameters then revertFunc not working (: